# how to make a tie in tic tac toe in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, tic-tac-toe

I'm making a tic-tac-toe game in react,so here i have my formula to search winner

```
  const lines = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
    if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
      return squares[a];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

this is where I am implementing the game

```
import Board from './Board';
import calculateWinner from './calculateWinner';

export default function Game() {
  const [board, setBoard] = useState(Array(9).fill(null));
  const [history, setHistory] = useState(board);
  const [xIsNext, setXIsNext] = useState(true);
  const [step, setStep] = useState(0);
  const winner = calculateWinner(board);

  const handleClick = index => {
    const boardCopy = board.slice();
    if (winner || boardCopy[index]) return;

    boardCopy[index] = xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';
    setBoard(boardCopy);
    setXIsNext(!xIsNext);
  };

  function startNewGame() {
    setBoard(Array(9).fill(null));
  }

  function whoIsNext() {
    if (winner) {
      return 'Выиграл ' + winner;
    } else if (!winner) {
      return 'Следующий ход: ' + (xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O');
    } else if (!xIsNext) {
      return 'tie';
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="game">
      <button onClick={startNewGame}> Начать заново</button>

      <Board squares={board} onClick={handleClick} />

      <p>{whoIsNext()}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Square from './Square';

export default function Board({ squares, onClick }) {
  return (
    <div className="game-board">
      {squares.map((square, index) => (
        <Square key={index} value={square} onClick={() => onClick(index)} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

import React from 'react';

export default function Square(props) {
  return (
    <button className="square" onClick={props.onClick}>
      {props.value}
    </button>
  );
}
```

I don't understand how can I get a draw? Do I need to change something in the formula for calculating the winner? or what am i missing
please, help me ti understand where  i have error

Comment: It's a draw if all tiles are filled and there is no winner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to check whether there is still a square that is free to play. In other words, if `board` has no more `null`, then it is a draw. You should still check if there is a winner first, but if not, the next thing to check is whether the board is full.

Note that your `if...else if...` chain should end with an `else` that is not followed by an `if`: it needs to be a "catch-all"... without further condition.

Here is a suggested change to your `whoIsNext` function:

```
  function whoIsNext() {
    if (winner) {
      return 'Выиграл ' + winner;
    } else if (board.includes(null)) { // Not yet full board
      return 'Следующий ход: ' + (xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O');
    } else { // Board is full -- it is a tie
      return 'tie';
    }
  }
```